# How to limit Berkeley DB's buffer?

Tags: c, buffer, berkeley-db

I need to limit the maximum size of Berkeley's buffer. I've tried using the code below, but the buffer keeps growing.

```
DB_ENV *db_env; 
u_int32_t env_flags;
char *DBNOMENV = "";
db_env_create(&db_env, 0);
db_env->set_cache_max(db_env, 0.1, 0);
env_flags = DB_CREATE | DB_INIT_MPOOL;
db_env->open(db_env, DBNOMENV, env_flags, 0);
DB *BDB_database;
db_create(&BDB_database, db_env, 0);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the stated purpose of [tag:cache-control]. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: Sorry, but the set_cache_max function seemed to control Berkeley's cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `DB_ENV->set_cachesize`:  [set_cachesize, from the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/api_reference/C/envset_cachesize.html).

What's the purpose of `set_cache_max`, when all it appears to do is limit the number you can specify with some other function call?  You got me.  There's probably some nuance here, but in practice, `set_cache_max` is only there to to add to the confusion.

Note that both of these functions only accept integer arguments for the sizing.  You'll need `set_cachesize(db_env, 0, 100*1024*1024, 1);` to do what you were trying to do with that `0.1`.

"Number of caches" should be 1.

Comment: Thanks, Mike Andrews. What happens when the buffer reaches its limit? I thought the system would do paging. But the following error occurred:
unable to allocate buffer cache space
DB->put error: : Unable to allocate memory

Comment: Unfortunately, there are quite a few reasons you might get `ENOMEM`.  You might try posting another question with the code you have.